# MediaPicker - When I select photo it is not shown on page but only on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to load image into application. I am following MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android. While UWP works great (tested only with emulator) I can not get it to work on Android (also tested only with emulator). App would save location with photo. I do not know if it matters, but first page is map, showing current location, and second page is page with error where I want to save location&photo.

When I choose photo it clear page (in case there is anything written in entry and editor both get cleared) and no picture is shown. Even label with photo path does not return anything. It is like it reloads page. I implemented option to take photo with same result.

When in debug mode all properties have value but when I choose/take photo properties values are not shown on UI.

ViewModel

```
using iVanApp.Model;
using iVanApp.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace iVanApp.ViewModels
{
    class AddNightViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public AddNightViewModel(INavService navService)
            : base(navService)
        {

        }
        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        string comment;
        public string Comment
        {
            get => comment;
            set
            {
                comment = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        string nameNight;
        public string NameNight
        {
            get => nameNight;
            set
            {
                nameNight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private async Task<string> GetAddressName(Location location)
        {
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder();
            // Position position = new Position(latitude.Value, longitude.Value);
            Position position = new Position(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
            string address = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<string> possibleAddress = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);
                address = possibleAddress.FirstOrDefault();
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Succes!", "Saved. Address is " + address, "OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error!", "Something went wrong\nError:\n" + ex.Message, "OK");
                
            }

            
            return address;
        }

        public Command SaveLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
               {
                   var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                   if (location == null)
                   {
                       var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                       cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                       location = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(request, cts.Token);
                   }
                   string addressName = string.Empty;
                   if (location != null)
                   {
                       addressName = await GetAddressName(location);
                   }

                   Night nightData = new Night
                   {
                       NightDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
                       NightLatitude = location.Latitude,
                       NightLongitute = location.Longitude,
                       NightName = NameNight,
                       Address = addressName,
                       Comments = Comment,
                       NightImage = PhotoPath
                       
                   };
                   await App.Database.SaveNightAsync(nightData);

               });
            }
        }
        string photoPath;
        public string PhotoPath
        {
            get => photoPath;
            set
            {
                photoPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        
        public Command SelectPhoto
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
               {
                   try
                   {
                       var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
                       await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
                       Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
                       await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Done",
                           $"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}",
                           "OK");
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
                       await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("ERROR",
                           $"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}",
                           "OK");
                   }

               });
            }
        }
        public Command TakePhoto
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
                        await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
                        //Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Done",
                            $"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}",
                            "OK");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
                        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error",
                            $"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}",
                            "OK");
                    }

                });
            }
        }
        async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
        {
            // canceled
            if (photo == null)
            {
                PhotoPath = null;
                return;
            }
            // save the file into local storage
            var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
            using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

            PhotoPath = newFile;
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="iVanApp.Views.AddNightView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Entry Text="{Binding NameNight}"/>
            <Editor Placeholder="Comments"
                    Text="{Binding Comment}"/>
            <Button Text="Choose photo"
                    Command="{Binding SelectPhoto}"
                   />
            <Button Text="Take photo"
                    Command="{Binding TakePhoto}"
                   />
            
            <Button Text="Save location" 
                    Command="{Binding SaveLocation}"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding PhotoPath}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoPath}"
                   HeightRequest="150"
                   Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Andoid rights- AssemblyInfo

```
// Needed for Picking photo/video
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage)]

// Needed for Taking photo/video
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera)]
```

And here is a log - when I click button to select picture and when I select picture.

```
02-25 01:10:00.293 W/ActivityThread(28782): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@f3053de
02-25 01:10:00.299 E/SchedPolicy(28782): set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
02-25 01:10:00.440 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
02-25 01:10:00.499 I/chatty  (28782): uid=10092(com.companyname.ivanapp) RenderThread identical 2 lines
02-25 01:10:00.524 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
02-25 01:10:01.270 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: /data/user/0/com.companyname.ivanapp/cache/IMG_20210224_063027.jpg
02-25 01:10:02.231 I/mono-stdout(28782): CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: /data/user/0/com.companyname.ivanapp/cache/IMG_20210224_063027.jpg
02-25 01:10:02.312 W/StaticLayout(28782): maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
02-25 01:10:02.320 I/chatty  (28782): uid=10092(com.companyname.ivanapp) identical 5 lines
02-25 01:10:02.320 W/StaticLayout(28782): maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:2 lineCount:2
02-25 01:10:02.499 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
02-25 01:10:02.708 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
02-25 01:10:04.406 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
02-25 01:10:04.408 D/OpenGLRenderer(28782): endAllActiveAnimators on 0xc12e6400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xc12a9d20
02-25 01:10:04.418 E/SchedPolicy(28782): set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
02-25 01:10:04.440 D/EGL_emulation(28782): eglMakeCurrent: 0xc7cd21e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xc7cfc0d0)
```

Any help/insight would be much appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

I tried to found an issue and build an testing app from scratch and testing when does MediaPicker stop working. This happens when I implement navigation. I did navigation based on book Mastering Xamarin.Forms (only up to part when it start using Framework. So I am navigation without framework).

My navigation is following

INavService

```
public interface INavService
{
    // Navigatze to another page without passing any parameter
    Task NavigateTo<TVM>()
        where TVM : BaseViewModel;
}
```

XamarinFormsNavService

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(XamarinFormsNavService))]

namespace TestMediaPicker_v2.Services
{
    public class XamarinFormsNavService : INavService
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Type, Type> _map = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

        // Creates dictionary of all ViewModels and coresponding Views
        public void RegistryViewMapping(Type viewModel, Type view)
        {
            _map.Add(viewModel, view);
        }

        public INavigation XamarinFormsNav { get; set; }


        // Navigation task for each VIewModel and coresponding View
        public async Task NavigateTo<TVM>() where TVM : BaseViewModel
        {
            await NavigateToView(typeof(TVM));
            if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel)
            {
                ((BaseViewModel)XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext).Init();
            }
        }

        async Task NavigateToView(Type ViewModelType)
        {
            if (!_map.TryGetValue(ViewModelType, out Type viewType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("No view found in view mapping for " + ViewModelType.FullName + ".");
            }

            // Use reflection to get the View's constructor and create an instance of the View
            var constructor = viewType.GetTypeInfo()
                .DeclaredConstructors
                .FirstOrDefault(dc => !dc.GetParameters().Any());
            var view = constructor.Invoke(null) as Page;
            await XamarinFormsNav.PushAsync(view, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Code behind of my view

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var viewModel = new AddNightViewModel(DependencyService.Get<INavService>());
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
```

Dictionary of views and viewModels in app.xaml.cs

```
 public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mainPage = new NavigationPage(new AddNightView());
            var navService = DependencyService.Get<INavService>() as XamarinFormsNavService;


            navService.XamarinFormsNav = mainPage.Navigation;
            navService.RegistryViewMapping(typeof(AddNightViewModel), typeof(AddNightView));
            navService.RegistryViewMapping(typeof(AllNightsViewModel), typeof(AllNightsView));
            MainPage = mainPage;
        }
```

Comment: I tested it with your code above and it worked fine.What's your android emulator version ?

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I also tried with fresh project and it works. So I think it is not because of emulator version. Also deployed original project  to 2 android phones and it does not work (app crashes). 
After I added other things on new project it stooped working. I added MVVM and SQLite. Now I will be adding thing by thing and tested so that I could see what cause this error. Or do you have any better idea how to approach this issue?

Comment: After much more investigating I found that this happen when I add navigation service. Note that I do not use any framework - navigation is done based on book Mastering Xamarin Forms. I will take a deeper look at navigation and try to see where I did the error.